# why this shows port error while running the application?

Tags: flutter

E/flutter ( 5985): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.153.192.23, port = 42423

Answer (score 0):

usually that error means that socket port is closed by a firewall, ore there is not a listener on that port that can accept your connection. Could you post some code where exception occur? maybe is only wrong port. (ie. each socket connection on internet is based on a IP address and Port, the port is a number that identify where a service is listening)

Comment: Future register()async {

    var url = "http://10.153.192.23/myapp/register.php";
    var response = await http.post(url, body: {
      "name": name.text,
      "pass": pass.text,

    });

  print(response.body);
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    if (data == "Error") {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "This user already exit",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0);

Comment: may i suggest you to use https://gorest.co.in/ to test your code? you there have some full working rest api that help you to prototype your app. i suspect that the problem is the rest service that is not up or working on the url: "10.153.192.23/myapp/register.php"

Comment: if you like i can provide some flutter code to join restful services online, that is full working because belongs on a commercial app i developed.

Answer (score 0):

```
  // this is the function which send a json packet to endpoint service.
Future<http.Response> _sendItalPostePacket(UploadBarcodeData data){
        developer.log("UploadManager: _sendItalPostePacket");
        developer.log("UploadManager: ${data.dump()}");
        developer.log("UploadManager: ${jsonEncode(data.toJson())}");
        String item='['+jsonEncode(data.toJson())+']';// here i add brackets because the server aspect list of strings ot only one.
       return http.post(
         endpoint,//** here is the URL of service endpoint**
         headers: <String, String>{
           'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
         },
         body:item, // here is the JSON
       );
      }

// this class provide the function toJson to encode all class items in a json string

class UploadBarcodeData
{
 int ID ;                             //progressivo nella sincronizzazione
 String IDGruppo ;                    //identificativo del gruppo di poste
 String Codice ;                      //codice letto
 String DataLettura ;               //data in cui è stata effettuata la lettura
 double LatX ;                        //latitudine (obbligatoria)
 double LatY ;                        //longitudine (obbligatoria)
 String IdEsito ;                     //identificativo del tipo di esitazione registrata
 bool IsSync ;                        //booleano che indica se sincronizzione ok
 String Image ;                       //stringa che contiene il base64 dell'immagine
Position position;

 UploadBarcodeData({this.Codice,this.DataLettura,this.position}){
   ID=1;
   IDGruppo = "cfb5b2de-c967-4d3f-b688-c6a15de15daa";
   IdEsito = "f4256e8c-cfca-49ee-bb60-a52a5f0ab2a3";
   Image="";
   IsSync=false;
   LatX=position.latitude;
   LatY=position.longitude;
 }

 @override
 void initState() {

 }


 Map<String,dynamic> toJson()=>{
   'ID':ID,
   'IDGruppo':IDGruppo,
   'Codice':Codice,
   'DataLettura':DataLettura,
   'LatX':LatX,
   'LatY':LatY,
   'IdEsito':IdEsito,
   'IsSync':IsSync,
   'Image':Image,
 };

 toString(){
   return Codice;
 }

 @override
 String dump(){
   developer.log("UploadBarcodeData: ${toJson().toString()}");
   return toJson().toString();
 }
}
```